# Using parse.com how do I concatenate a query to return results from two separate query.equalTo?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and javaScript SDK.

I've got the following query. I need it to return results for both

```
query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
query.equalTo("toUser", currentUser);
```

As per below it can only return either or, not both. How do I concatenate these too make it work with both?

Do I do one query then nest another below it? or is there a better approach?

---

```
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

    var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
    query.include('toUser');
    query.include('SentTo');
    query.include("myBadge");
    query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
    query.equalTo("toUser", currentUser);
    query.equalTo("status", "Connected");

    query.find({
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can use is the [`Parse.Query.or`](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-compound) function.

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

var queryOne = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
queryOne.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);

var queryTwo = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
queryTwo.equalTo("toUser", currentUser);

var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryOne, queryTwo);
mainQuery.equalTo("status", "Connected");
mainQuery.find({ /* ... */ });
```

Comment: ok, if you look at my original post, it has 3 levels that the find results must return, the two that you have addressed above, and the 3rd that the users must have a status of "connected" Is it possible to include these into the above? Thanks very much

Comment: hmmm still seems to be returning all results and not just the "Connected" users :-/ Any ideas? would a jfiddle help?

Comment: Oh, you want Connected AND from currentUser OR to currentUser. Check the updated answer.

Comment: getting there, thanks so much - Is there any issues with the latest code working with pointers?

Comment: If the query is working, could you start a new question? Your second question isn't what the title implies. If you link it here, I'll look into it.

Comment: ok clear, Ive accepted your anser here and have posted the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024052/parse-query-working-but-results-showing-as-undefined-or-not-found